# Logistic regression with only 1 dummy variable

Tags: regression, logistic, python, econometrics

I have the following dataframe in Python:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                   'group': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b','b', 'b','b','c','c','c'],
                   'val':[1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1]})

print(df)
id group  val
0   1     a    1
1   2     a    0
2   3     a    1
3   4     b    0
4   5     b    1
5   6     b    1
6   7     b    0
7   8     c    0
8   9     c    1
9  10     c    1
```

I want to see if **ANY** of the levels of `group` has a significant effect on `val`.

So I do a logistic regression as follows:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

dummy_variables = pd.get_dummies(df['group'], drop_first=False)

logit_model = sm.Logit(df['val'], dummy_variables)
result = logit_model.fit()

print(result.summary())
```

Notice the `drop_first=False` and I also do not add a constant in the model, due to multicollinearity.

At my real data (not the dummy example) i get a `p-value < 0.05` for `dummy_a` and a `p-value > 0.05` for `dummy_b` and `dummy_c`.

Is it right to say that `a` has a signifficant effect on `val` ?

Comment: Many similar questions here:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/424633/overall-significance-of-a-categorical-variables-in-logistic-regression,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24298/can-i-ignore-coefficients-for-non-significant-levels-of-factors-in-a-linear-mode,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71832/what-do-p-values-for-levels-of-a-categorical-variable-represent-in-poisson-regre